# How to dispatch my variable with redux?

Tags: redux, redux-observable

I'm new to redux.
I realized that I need dispatch to save variables in our store.
However, I can't dispatch device_token.
I tried "store.dispatch".

and It's react-native code.
However, I think it is an only redux problem.
I need help.

my code is below.

```
// @flow
import { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import FCM, { FCMEvent, RemoteNotificationResult, 
WillPresentNotificationResult, NotificationType } from 'react-native-fcm';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getDeviceToken } from '../common/CurrentUser/actions';

const showLocalNotification = (notif) => {
  FCM.presentLocalNotification({
    title: notif.title,
    body: notif.body,
    priority: 'high',
    click_action: notif.click_action,
    show_in_foreground: true,
    local: true,
  });
};

export class PushNotification extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }

componentDidMount() {
  FCM.requestPermissions().then( () => {
    FCM.getFCMToken().then((token: string) => {
      const device_token = token;
      const { saveDeviceToken } = this.props;
      alert(device_token);
      dispatch(saveDeviceToken(device_token))
      //dispatch(getDeviceToken( { device_token }));
      alert(token);
    });
  });

  FCM.on(FCMEvent.RefreshToken, token => {
    alert(token);
  });


  this.notificationListner = FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, (notif: Object) => {
  if (notif.local_notification) {
    return;
  }
  if (notif.opened_from_tray) {
    return;
  }

  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    switch (notif._notificationType) {
      case NotificationType.Remote:
        notif.finish(RemoteNotificationResult.NewData);
        break;
      case NotificationType.NotificationResponse:
        notif.finish();
        break;
      case NotificationType.WillPresent:
        notif.finish(WillPresentNotificationResult.All);
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
    }
      showLocalNotification(notif);
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.notificationListner.remove();
    this.refreshTokenListener.remove();
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  return {
    saveDeviceToken: (token) => dispatch(getDeviceToken(token)),
  };
};

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(PushNotification);
```

// action.types.js

```
// @flow
import type { Action } from './actionTypes';
import type { User } from '../../entities';

export const SUCCESS_LOGIN = 'SUCCESS_LOGIN';
export const GET_DEVICE_TOKEN = 'GET_DEVICE_TOKEN';

export const successLogin = (payload: { user: User, authToken: string }): Action =>
  ({ type: 'SUCCESS_LOGIN', payload });

export const getDeviceToken = (payload: { device_token: string }): Action =>
  ({ type: 'GET_DEVICE_TOKEN', payload });
```

// reducer.js

```
export default (state: State = INITIAL_STATE, action: Action): State => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'GET_DEVICE_TOKEN':
    return {
      state,
    };
  default:
    return state;
  }
};
```

Do you have any Idea?
I can't dispatch my device_token.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of `connect` is `mapStateToProps`.  If you don't need to map any state to props, you can just change it to:

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PushNotification);
```

This will bypass that parameter and allow `mapDispatchToProps` to be passed as the second parameter.

Then you can just call it off props like a function

```
componentDidMount() {
  FCM.requestPermissions().then( () => {
   FCM.getFCMToken().then((token: string) => {
      const device_token = token;
      const { saveDeviceToken } = this.props;
      saveDeviceToken(device_token);
    });
  });
}
```

Please see the [API docs for more details](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options).

---

I think you are also not passing the `device_token` to the `getDeviceToken` action creator correctly.  Try changing `mapDispatchToProps` to look like

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  return {
    saveDeviceToken: (token) => dispatch(getDeviceToken({ device_token: token })),
  };
};
```

Comment: thank you Michael.
However, I got the errer ''undefined is not an object (evaluating'state.currentUser.payload.device_token')'
I need fix another error.
realy thanks

Comment: @sonicmario hello! if his answer indeed solved that particular issue, please hit the checkmark to accept it https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 Other follow up questions should be made in a different SO question. Thanks!

Comment: it did NOT work.
I cannot see GET_DEVICE_TOKEN on my console.

Comment: @sonicmario I have updated my answer with another potential issue.  There seems to be a few issues that might be causing cascading failures.  For what it's worth, `state.currentUser` does not appear anywhere in the code you have shared, so my initial answer does appear to have got you passed the immediate hurdle, but you have run up against a new issue.

Comment: where would it get saved to the redux store?

Comment: That would depend entirely on the reducer.  In the shared code, the reducer does not actually do anything with `action.payload` so it's not actually stored anywhere.  If that reducer gets combined with any others would also have an affect on where is gets saved.  I suggest asking a specific question if you are having an issue.